# Views taxonomy weight - choose which vocabulary?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I have 2 vocabularies. In Views, if I add the node taxonomy term weight as a field, I can't specify a vocabulary to use. The same vocabulary is always used, but I want it to be the other vocabulary that is being used currently. How does Drupal decide which one to use and how can I change it to the other?

Comment: Anyone? Admittedly I have no idea how to do this, but I would have thought the solution should be something simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal but ive solved this by filtering by a vocabulary. The vocabulary ive filtered by is the one that contains the terms who's weight I want to use.

This is OK for me as all my nodes will have a term from each vocabulary. The limitation of the method is that if I filter by vocabulary1, if a node only belongs to a term from vocabulary2, even on the term page it wont show up.